# How to convert HTML to readable text - Python

Tags: python, html, text

How do I convert this text to being readable (removing all the </mtext> i.e.
I already tried using html2text, but it only removed the < p >, and I need everything removed.'

I want it like on https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/html-to-text/
not like on https://www.textfixer.com/html/html-to-text.php
`<p>Du kan g\u00f8re det s\u00e5dan her:<\/p><p><math><mrow><munder><mrow><munder><mrow><mtable><mtr><mtd><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mover><mrow><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>4297<\/mn><\/mrow><mrow><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>1<\/mn><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>1<\/mn><mo>\u2062<\/mo><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><\/mrow><\/mover><\/mtd><\/mtr><mtr><mtd><munder><mrow><mtable><mtr><mtd><mo>+<\/mo><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>1425<\/mn><\/mtd><\/mtr><\/mtable><\/mrow><mo>\u0332<\/mo><\/munder><\/mtd><\/mtr><mtr><mtd><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>5722<\/mn><\/mtd><\/mtr><\/mtable><\/mrow><mo>\u0332<\/mo><\/munder><\/mrow><mo>\u0332<\/mo><\/munder><\/mrow><\/math><\/p>`

Comment: Does this help? https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-extract-text-from-an-html-file-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's anything you want here.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils
html = '''
<p>Du kan g\u00f8re det s\u00e5dan her:<\/p><p><math><mrow><munder><mrow><munder><mrow><mtable><mtr><mtd><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mover><mrow><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>4297<\/mn><\/mrow><mrow><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>1<\/mn><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>1<\/mn><mo>\u2062<\/mo><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><\/mrow><\/mover><\/mtd><\/mtr><mtr><mtd><munder><mrow><mtable><mtr><mtd><mo>+<\/mo><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>1425<\/mn><\/mtd><\/mtr><\/mtable><\/mrow><mo>\u0332<\/mo><\/munder><\/mtd><\/mtr><mtr><mtd><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>5722<\/mn><\/mtd><\/mtr><\/mtable><\/mrow><mo>\u0332<\/mo><\/munder><\/mrow><mo>\u0332<\/mo><\/munder><\/mrow><\/math><\/p>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.text)
print (doc.removeHtml(html))
print (doc.replaceReg(html,'<[^>]*>','').strip())
print (doc.replaceReg(doc.replaceReg(html,'<[^>]*>',''),'[ ]+',' ').strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<p>Du kan g\u00f8re det s\u00e5dan her:<\/p><p><math><mrow><munder><mrow><munder><mrow><mtable><mtr><mtd><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mover><mrow><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>4297<\/mn><\/mrow><mrow><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>1<\/mn><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>1<\/mn><mo>\u2062<\/mo><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><\/mrow><\/mover><\/mtd><\/mtr><mtr><mtd><munder><mrow><mtable><mtr><mtd><mo>+<\/mo><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>1425<\/mn><\/mtd><\/mtr><\/mtable><\/mrow><mo>\u0332<\/mo><\/munder><\/mtd><\/mtr><mtr><mtd><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>5722<\/mn><\/mtd><\/mtr><\/mtable><\/mrow><mo>\u0332<\/mo><\/munder><\/mrow><mo>\u0332<\/mo><\/munder><\/mrow><\/math><\/p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# remove the script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()
    
# extract the text
text = soup.get_text()

print(text)
```

Comment: It ended up giving me `Du kan f.eks. g\u00f8re s\u00e5dan her:<\p>`
It completely skipped important numbers like these (bold doesn't work for some reason, so between ** and **, that's supposed to be bold):
`<\/mtext><mn>**4297**<\/mn><\/mrow><mrow><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext> <\/mtext><mn>**1**<\/mn><mtext> <\/mtext><mtext>`

That's when I used `soup.p.get_text().replace("\n", "")` because I wan't to keep the whitespaces

Comment: my current code:
`soup = BeautifulSoup(questions[0])
        for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
          script.decompose()
        ques = soup.p.get_text().replace("\n", "")`

questions[0] just equals the string you had above

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand. What's your desired output? It gave me `Du kan gøre det sådan her:             4297    1   1⁢    +    1425̲               5722̲̲`, which seems to preserve the spaces okay?